# How to get the data from the internet more efficiently?

Tags: java, android

In my app, I make a request from a public URL, and then open the source code of the web page, finally, I extract the information that I want from the source code. I got no problem with this entire process. However, it takes so long to load up the information I want. Is there any other efficient way I can do?

```
public class GetMethodEx {

    public String getInternetData(String currentUrl) throws Exception{
        BufferedReader in = null;
        String data = null;
        try{
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            URI website = new URI(currentUrl);
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(website);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String l = "";
            String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while((l = in.readLine()) !=null){
                sb.append(l + nl);
            }
            in.close();
            data = sb.toString();
            return data;
        }finally{
            if (in != null){
                try{
                    in.close();
                    return data;
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: What website are you getting data from. THey may have an API you can use to speed up the process significantly.

Answer (score 0):

Using a StringBuffer is really not efficient downloading large texts as a html file is one. Since you are reading line java has to allocate memory for each line you are reading just to copy everything that has been copied in memory into the StringBuffer what leads to intense GC work. Then a StringBuffer has a fixed size so your program may reach a point where the StringBuffers size is exceeded which leads to a resizing of the StringBuffer what causes copying everything inside the Buffer into a new one.
So you rather should try to get the size of html document you requested and read everything into a char array. That may not work since http allows to transfer data in chunks of variable size. This is an idea of what you can do if that is the case:

```
String html = "";
CharBuffer buff = CharBuffer.allocate(16384);

int read = in.read(buff);
while(read > -1) {
    while(read > -1 && buff.remaining > 0) {
        read = in.read(buff);
    }
    html += new String(buff.array());
    buff.clear();
}
```

Comment: You would be correct if he was appending strings to strings, but the overhead of StringBuffer is insignificant compared to the network overhead.